# ViewHelper Uri Fluid does not render link

Tags: html, typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

I have the following code within my Partial:

```
<f:if condition="{pager.currentPage} != {pager.nextPage}">
  <v:page.header>
    <link rel="next" href="{f:uri.page pageUid=\'10\'}" />
  </v:page.header>
</f:if>
```

I expected that this would add a header `<link>` tag with an actual link in the `href`part of the tag.

However, i only get the following within my `<head>` tag:

```
<link rel="next" href="{f:uri.page pageUid=\'10\'}">
```

So i assume that the ViewHelper isn`t called. The if section is evaluated correctly, so i have access to fluid.

This is just a minimal failing example, i stumbled upon rendering a more complex f:uri.action call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `{f:uri.page(pageUid: 10)}`.